# Atribuir Valor à um Array Fora do Método

Tags: java

Preciso atribuir um valor a um Array e jogá-lo para fora de um método, mas para isso preciso pegar os valores que são obtidos através desse método, para posteriormente usar esse Array obtido em outros métodos ou classes. O print dentro do método aparece de forma correta. Agora quando passo para o Array ele não atribui corretamente os valores. Não sei se a forma como o código foi feito é correta para isso?

Segue código feito até agora...

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CombBusca {

    private int numeros[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    private int quantidade = 3;
    private int resultado[] = new int[3];
    private int count = 0;
    public String[] novosresultados;

    private void busca(int inicio,int fim, int profundidade){

        String todosresultados = "";

        if ( (profundidade + 1) >= quantidade)
        for(int x = inicio; x <= fim; x++){
            resultado[profundidade] = numeros[x];
            // faz alguma coisa com um dos resultados possiveis
            count++;
            //Criei aqui a String para posteriormente passar para o Array 
            todosresultados = resultado[0] + ", " + resultado[1] + ", " + resultado[2];
            System.out.println(resultado[0] + ", " + resultado[1] + ", " + resultado[2]);
        } else
            for(int x = inicio; x <= fim; x++){
                resultado[profundidade] = numeros[x];
                busca(x + 1,fim + 1,profundidade + 1);
        }
        // Novo Array para jogar fora do método "busca" e usar em outros metodos ou classes
        novosresultados = todosresultados.split(", ");
        // Aqui quando mando o print é que acontece o erro
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(novosresultados));

    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

        CombBusca comb = new CombBusca();
        comb.busca(0, (5-3), 0);

        System.out.println("Total de combinacoes: " + comb.count);

       }
   }
```

Saída:

> [1, 2, 5]
>   [1, 3, 5]
>   [1, 4, 5]
>   []
>   [2, 3, 5]
>   [2, 4, 5]
>   []
>   [3, 4, 5]
>   []
>   []
>   Total de combinacoes: 10

Modo esperado:

> 1, 2, 3
>   1, 2, 4
>   1, 2, 5
>   1, 3, 4
>   1, 3, 5
>   1, 4, 5
>   2, 3, 4
>   2, 3, 5
>   2, 4, 5
>   3, 4, 5
>   Total de combinacoes: 10

Comment: Tentei dá forma sugerida, mas não são geradas todas as combinações. Sempre no final de cada linha exibe o numero 5:

Comment: 1, 2, 5
1, 3, 5
1, 4, 5
1, 4, 5
2, 3, 5
2, 4, 5
2, 4, 5
3, 4, 5
3, 4, 5
3, 4, 5
Total de combinacoes: 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não há nada errado com seu código. A saída também está correta.

O que ocorre é que a variável `todosresultados` é local e ao sair da última recursão ela está vazia, fazendo o programa imprimir `'[]'` no console.

Para evitar esse inconveniente, faça um teste de conteúdo antes de imprimi-la:

```
if (todosresultados.length() > 0)
            // Novo Array para jogar fora do método "busca" e usar em outros metodos ou classes
            novosresultados = todosresultados.split(", ");
```

Ou opte por sumprimir essa impressão do código, já que não faz sentido pois o seu resultado sempre é igual a linha anterior.

Retire o código abaixo:

```
if (todosresultados.length() > 0) {
        // Novo Array para jogar fora do método "busca" e usar em outros metodos ou classes
        novosresultados = todosresultados.split(", ");
        // Aqui quando mando o print é que acontece o erro
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(novosresultados));
        }
```

**UPDATE**

Após seu comentário consegui entender realmente o que você deseja.

A questão principal é que você não está adicionando a variável `novosresultados`, mas sim sobrescrevendo seus dados pela última execução do método `busca()`.

Para solução, primeiramente substitua a declaração da variável `novosresultados` por:

```
private static List<String> novosresultados = new ArrayList<String>();
```

O tipo `List` é melhor para quem está iniciando, além de tornara implementação mais fácil para este caso se comparado à um vetor.

Depois, substitua a linha:

```
System.out.println(resultado[0] + ", " + resultado[1] + ", " + resultado[2]);
```

por

```
novosresultados.add(todosresultados);
```

O método `add` do objeto `List` não sobrescreve os dados anteriores, e sim adicionada mais dados na lista.

Por último retire do código a minha sugestão anterior, pois não será mais necessária:

```
if (todosresultados.length() > 0) {
    // Novo Array para jogar fora do método "busca" e usar em outros metodos ou classes
    novosresultados = todosresultados.split(", ");
    // Aqui quando mando o print é que acontece o erro
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(novosresultados));
}
```

Seu código ficará dessa forma:

```
public class ComBusca {

    private int numeros[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    private int quantidade = 3;
    private int resultado[] = new int[3];
    private int count = 0;
    private static List<String> novosresultados = new ArrayList<String>();

    private void busca(int inicio,int fim, int profundidade){

        String todosresultados = "";

        if ( (profundidade + 1) >= quantidade)
            for(int x = inicio; x <= fim; x++){
                resultado[profundidade] = numeros[x];

            // faz alguma coisa com um dos resultados possiveis
            count++;
            //Criei aqui a String para posteriormente passar para o Array 
            todosresultados = resultado[0] + ", " + resultado[1] + ", " + resultado[2];
            novosresultados.add(todosresultados);
        } else
            for(int x = inicio; x <= fim; x++){
                resultado[profundidade] = numeros[x];
                busca(x + 1,fim + 1,profundidade + 1);
            }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

        ComBusca comb = new ComBusca();
        comb.busca(0, (5-3), 0);

        //Aqui imprimo o resultado da lista, fora do método busca
        for (String r : novosresultados)
            System.out.println(r);

        System.out.println("Total de combinacoes: " + comb.count);

   }
}
```

Comment: Tentei dá forma sugerida, mas não são geradas todas as combinações. Sempre no final de cada linha exibe o numero 5. Veja:
1, 2, 5                                                                                                     1, 3, 5                                                                                                      1, 4, 5                                                                                                         2, 3, 5....

Comment: Como eu sugeri, retire do código essa parte da impressão, pois sempre será impresso o valor da última recursão. Editei a resposta.

Comment: Veja bem, a dúvida é como trabalhar com o resultado da String "todosresultados" fora do método "busca". Mesmo retirando essa parte do codigo ainda não conseguirei tornar essa String publica. Ou seja, preciso que toda vez que chamar o método "busca" eu armazene o resultado em um Array, com todas as combinações, para posteriormente trabalhar com essa Array em outro método ou por outra classe. Dessa forma pegarei essa Array onde foi inserido o resultado da "busca" para fazer novas combinações, através de outros métodos ou outras classes. Não sei se consegui esclarecer mais a ideia é essa.

Comment: Completando......O código que coloquei no post é só um exemplo das inúmeras tentativas que fiz para armazenar o resultado da busca em um Array e poder trabalhar com esse resultado posteriormente por outro método ou até mesmo outra classe, para fazer outras combinações. Em outras tentativas, o Array só armazenava a última combinação, das 10 possíveis. Então o que preciso não é apenas printar o resultado, mas armazenar esse resultado em um Array e tornar esse Array publico, para usar em outros métodos ou classes.

Comment: Agora consegui entender o que você deseja. Editei a resposta com a solução.

Comment: Era exatamente isso!!! Bem mais simples do que achava que era, passei próximo algumas vezes, mas sempre entendia que tinha de jogar o resultado para fora do método e não atribuir os resultados dentro do próprio método. Agora consegui entender.....Valeu!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu entendi você está tentando imprimir todas as permutações de um array.

Caso seja isso, tem o ***Heap's Algorithms*** que faz isso.

Tem um material do **Robert Sandwick** muito bacana que fala sobre o algoritmo (em inglês).

> http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~goodman/22m150.dir/2007/Permutation%20Generation%20Methods.pdf

Alguns exemplos de implementação:

> http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Permutations.java.html
>   http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/PermutationsLex.java.html

Código em Java

```
public class HeapsAlgorithms {  
    public void generate( int n, int[] a ){
        if( n ==  1 )
            System.out.println( Arrays.toString(a));
        else{
            for( int i = 0; i < n - 1; i ++ ){
                generate( n - 1, a );
                if( n % 2 == 0 ){
                    swap( a, i, n-1 );
                }else {
                    swap( a, 0, n-1 );
                }
            }
            generate( n - 1, a );
        }
    }

    private void swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {
        int temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HeapsAlgorithms hp = new HeapsAlgorithms();

        hp.generate( 4 , new int[]{1,2,3,4} );
    }
}
```

> **fonte**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap's_algorithm

Comment: Posso dizer que esse método já é um pouco avançado, ainda estou começando a aprender java. Sim, seria uma permutação, mas sem repetições. Nesse exemplo os resultados se repetem, embora não na mesma ordem.